# How can I efficiently test that a parser handles multiple levels of operator precedence correctly?

Tags: unit-testing, parsing, operator-precedence

I'm working on a parser for a (very small) toy language, and I want to test that it's parsing expressions with the appropriate precedence. Previously I just had arithmetic operators, so there weren't many possible combinations of operations; however, now I'm adding logical/relational operations, which means there are many more possible expressions. I'm not sure how best to test the parser without writing an excessive number of unit tests covering every possible combination of operators. How can I go about writing a reasonable number of tests that make sure all operator precedence is handled correctly?

Comment: (semi-serious) Auto-generate a large number of random expressions and compare the results with that computed by an external evaluator in a compatible language.

Comment: @KilianFoth I mean, I've definitely been thinking along those lines, perhaps using some sort of property-based testing.

Comment: An auto generator should be able to compute an expected answer, if it knows the operator precedence.  One long test should be able to test all operators in combination ;)

Answer (score 2):

“A reasonable number of tests” in this case is pretty large. Since each test will be tiny and very quick to write, it shouldn’t be a big deal. Spend an hour or so now and you’re done.

And honestly, you don’t need to test *every* combination since you only need a few tests to prove `a < b : b < c :: a < c`.

Comment: I was thinking about using some sort of approach using transitivity (prove `a < b`, `b < c`, `c < d`, then show that the relation is transitive), but I'm not sure how to test that transitivity holds in general. I might just take the advice in your first paragraph and just crank them out.